# The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I installed like these...

sonarqube-6.2 | sonar-scanner-2.8 | sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24 | msbuild 14

And I made windows batch file to build and scan(sonar). but some projects are ok. but some projects are failed.

batch file is...

> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:%PROJECT_KEY% /n:%PROJECT_NAME% /v:%BUILD_VERSION% /d:sonar.verbose=true
>
> MSBuild.exe "projects" /t:build /v:m
>
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

error message is...

> SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
>   Default properties file was found at C:\SONARQUBE\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
>   Loading analysis properties from C:\SONARQUBE\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
>   Post-processing started.
>   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
>   18:50:20.591  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
>   18:50:20.592  Not running under TeamBuild
>   18:50:20.593  Analysis base directory: C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube
>   Build directory: 
>   Bin directory: C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\bin
>   Config directory: C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\conf
>   Output directory: C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\out
>   Config file: C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
>   Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
>   The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
>
> Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
> 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
>
> Writing processing summary to C:\jenkins_slave_buildpc\workspace\amis3_client_sonar.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
>   Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
>   18:50:20.615  Creating a summary markdown file...
>   18:50:20.617  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

I executed same batch file for sonar. but some project is ok. and some project is failed.. 
What makes this error message?

Comment: The Scanner for MsBuild integrates closely with msbuild. If your build is heavily customized, it can happen that we don't find all the pieces that we need. For example, you might have a project that has no output. This would most likely fail the sonar analysis. Try to identify which project types cause the problem. (Previously we had problem with WebPages (not WebSites) projects which have no compile targets.)

Comment: thank you. I will check each projects's configs.

Answer (score 4):

I got the similar error when trying to run `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end` command in teamcity.
Begin step and MSBuild step to build project was working fine.

When I given full path for runner and MSbuild in teamcity. It worked for me.

```
C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\MSBuild.Sonarqube.runner.exe 
begin /k:"Sonar key here" /n:"Sonar project here" /v:%build.number% 
/d:sonar.log.level=DEBUG 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" [path for .sln file 
here] /t:Rebuild 
/p:VisualStudioversion=14.0;Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"

C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\MSBuild.Sonarqube.runner end
```

Comment: Might be an MSbuild.exe version issue. Had a similar problem and apparently, my solution was build in vs2017 but the path variable was pointing to an old .net framework 4.x msbuild (my project is .net core). Changed the path variable to point to the corrent msbuild.exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin - In mycase).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing worth checking--especially if you're trying to run SonarQube from a build server--is whether it is operating in the local system profile. From the logs, you may see something like:

```
Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
```

I found that this path did not exist, even though SonarQube's scanner happily claimed to have installed its targets there. My solution was to create a build agent account for executing the build tasks. This will cause SonarQube to install its targets to the user profile MSBuild folder. For example:

```
C:\Users\buildagent\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
```